# How to remove empty lines that are being generated in a log file from morgan logger?

Tags: node.js, logging, winston, morgan

I am getting blank lines in output as seen below 
I am using morgan and winston combined here for logging into a file
how to avoid those blank lines ?

```
//logger 
const logger = new winston.Logger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({
            filename: './logs/dca_ui.log',
            handleExceptions: true,
            json: false,
            maxsize: MAX_SIZE_LOG,
            maxFiles: MAX_LOG_FILES,
            colorize: false,
        }),
     ],
     exitOnError: false,
});

//writestream
const stream = {
    write: (message, encoding) => {
        logger.info(message);
    },
};

app.use((morgan(':date :status :method :url :response-time', { stream: stream })));
```

Output:

> 5  2016-11-15T04:21:18.981Z - info: Tue, 15 Nov 2016 04:21:18 GMT 200 GET /index.js 4.539
>   
> 6
>   
> 7  2016-11-15T04:21:19.786Z - info: Tue, 15 Nov 2016 04:21:19 GMT 200 GET /urest/v1/template?start=0&count=20&sort=templateName:asc 106.379
>   
> 8
>   
> 9  2016-11-15T04:21:22.835Z - info: Tue, 15 Nov 2016 04:21:22 GMT 200 GET /urest/v1/template/7b4ca205-7b75-459c-81f1-a61fc8b6be69?view=condense 122.692

Answer (score 16):

morgan adds \n - new line in the end of a stream.
You can see it if you log this: 
`logger.info(JSON.stringify(message));`

So to remove it you'll need something like this:

```
//writestream
const stream = {
    write: (message, encoding) => {
        logger.info(message.substring(0,message.lastIndexOf('\n')));
    },
};
```

here is the discussion about it:
https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/issues/70

Answer (score 4):

I've an update on the question because I also encountered this

```
const stream = {
    write: (message) => {
        logger.http(message.trim());
    },
};
```